# Error attempting to get column ''0'' from result set. Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Column ''0'' not found

Tags: mybatis

## Question?

how can i support this feature like：

```
<collection property="approvalDomainList" ofType="com.icss.ebu.spms.asset.api.model.ApprovalDomain"
                    column="{id= id,approveType='0'}" select="findApprovalDomainList"></collection>
```

here is **approveType='0'**， this **0** is a specific value, I want to pass a fixed value instead of a table field。
but the log print **“org.apache.ibatis.executor.result.ResultMapException: Error attempting to get column ''0'' from result set.  Cause: java.sql.SQLException: Column ''0'' not found.”**

### MyBatis version

3.5.7

Comment: You may have to add the constant to the column list with alias i.e. `select id, ..., '0' approve_type from ...`. Then specify the alias in the nested select : `<collection ... column="{id=id,approveType=approve_type}" ...`.